# Javascript setTimeout not working properly, smooth scroll

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have made the following messy javascript that should smoothly scroll the page 128px above a div.

The script scrolls the page to the right place, but without being smooth.

This is because i can not get the function setTimeout working properly.

```
function pageScroll()
{   
    var from_top=$("#body_box_title_skills").offset().top;  

    scroll_speed = 15;
    goto_px = from_top - 128;

    times_scroll = goto_px / scroll_speed; 
    times_scroll = times_scroll.toString();

    times_scroll_array = times_scroll.split(".");
    times_scroll_array[1] = "0."+times_scroll_array[1];

    px_scroll_extra = times_scroll_array[1] * scroll_speed;

    scrollto_px = 0;

    while (times_scroll_array[0] >= 1)
    {
        scrollto_px = scrollto_px + scroll_speed;
        setTimeout(function(){window.scrollTo(0,scrollto_px)}, 1000);
        times_scroll_array[0]--;
    }
    scrollto_px = scrollto_px + px_scroll_extra;
    window.scrollTo(0,scrollto_px);

}
```

Comment: it looks like you are moving every second, it would probably be smoother if you reduced this time and the amount moved (and just moved more times).

Comment: Define "not smooth". Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: setTimeout() is *asynchronous*: it is not a "stop what you're doing, wait, do this, then start up again"; it's a "remind yourself to do this later, but also keep going with everything else I'm telling you."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are closing over the same variable `scrollto_px` in your `setTimeout`. When the `setTimeout` function actually runs, the value of `scrollto_px` is the same value it had at the end of the loop, so you just immediately scroll to that last value. You need to copy to a new variable that your `setTimeout` can close over.

Your second problem is that you are setting a timeouts that all trigger at almost the same time. You need to chain your timeouts so that the first timeout occurs after 1000 seconds, and the next occurs 1000 seconds after that. Note that `setTimeout` isn't the same as `sleep` in other languages. It doesn't suspend execution.

Your third problem is that you have these lines:

```
scrollto_px = scrollto_px + px_scroll_extra;
window.scrollTo(0,scrollto_px);
```

After your while loop which will automatically jump all the way to the end.

Here's one way to fix the problems you are having. I removed your `while` loop and added a function that will call itself again after a timeout:

```
function doScroll() {
    if (times_scroll_array[0] >= 1) {
        scrollto_px = scrollto_px + scroll_speed;
        console.log(scrollto_px);
        window.scrollTo(0, scrollto_px);
        times_scroll_array[0]--;
        setTimeout(doScroll, 100);
    } else {
        scrollto_px = scrollto_px + px_scroll_extra;
        window.scrollTo(0, scrollto_px);
    }
}
doScroll();
```

You can see it running here (I changed the timing because 1 second between steps was really slow - but you can adjust it as needed): http://jsfiddle.net/KqRwx/

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast and great reply, I really appreciate your effort. The script is up and running exactly as i wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you run the that function, the whole function is run in its entirety before any of the timeouts are triggered.
What you really want is something like this

```
function pageScroll(goto_px) {   
    var current_scroll = ( (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop) - (document.documentElement.clientTop || 0) );
    var scroll_speed = 15;
    // if we are less then 15 px from the destination, scroll whatever is left to go
    if ( Math.abs(goto_px - current_scroll) <= scroll_speed) {
        window.scrollTo(0, goto_px);
    } else {
        // scroll 15 pixels in the direction where the destination is
        window.scrollTo(0, current_scroll + ((current_scroll < goto_px ? 1 : -1) * scroll_speed) );
        window.setTimeout(function(){pageScroll(goto_px)}, 1000);
    }
}


pageScroll( $("#body_box_title_skills").offset().top - 128 );
```

Basically, call the function with the destination, the function calculates the current position of the window, and scrolls toward the destination once, and creates a timeout calling itself.
This function is by no means perfect though, as you can easily get a endless loop by invoking scrolls in opposite directions in which case you will be just scrolling back and fourth in to infinity. Additional steps should be taken to ensure that only one instance is running at any one time.

Also manually scrolling the page in the middle of the smooth scroll will cause the page to continue scrolling until the destination is reached, and listening to the scroll event to cancel the timeout does not seem to be a feasible solution due to window.scrollTo also triggering it. One idea would be to keep track of current scroll and cancel the timeout if it jumps unexpectedly.

An additional note: I'm not sure if [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) is applicable here, but to get consistent, as smooth as possible animations in general this is what you want to use. Might be worth reading.

Comment: Thank you for your time, effort and the explanation. Your script looks very professional. But I can't get it to work. I must be implementing it wrongly I think.